# WordPress Meta Title Separator

Tags: seo, headers

This code, when used in the header, automatically adds a arrow to wp_title.
How do I remove this?

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation for wp_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_title), as there are several things you can do to format it how you want.

Using the following code will remove the double arrows in the title:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title("",true); ?></title>
```